# Multiple Mongoose Schemas on one Express route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

new to web development and couldn't find an answer anywhere. Just wondering if it possible to have multiple mongoose schemas on a single express route?

something like this maybe

```
    // Add PurchaseOrder Form
router.get('/add', (req, res) => {

  Engineer.find({})
  .then(engineer => {
    res.render("purchaseorders/add", {
      engineer
    });
  });
  POcategory.find({})
  .then(pocategory => {
    res.render("purchaseorders/add", {
      pocategory
    });
  });

});
```

I thought about having them in variables but I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm basically trying to have drop down fields populated by my mongodb database on several fields and using multiple schemas.

Comment: You can define several local variables for the view. `res.render("purchaseorders/add", { engineer, pocategory }`. 
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Comment: Using the `GET` method for an endpoint named `/add` is weird though.
https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/